# .NET MVC 5 Why to use Gulp over MVC's default bundler

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, gulp, bower

So I decided to manage my client libraries with bower and added bower.json file into my VS2015 solution, configured it and it works well. However, I noticed that in almost all of the articles, people remove the default bundler and add Gulp or Grunt bundler into the project. What's wrong with the default bundler? I mean using Bowler instead of NuGet makes perfect sense for client library management but changing what works really well didn't make sense to me. Therefore, what are the advantages of Gulp/Grunt bundlers over MVC's default bundler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gulp/Grunt is way forward rather then MVC default bundler and it is not because which one do the bundling/minification better, but the main reason is that what other features are available because client side is just not about bundling and minification. Lot of other things are also involved like

- CSS pre-processing (LESS, SASS)
- CSS minification
- Image minification
- HTML minification
- Deployment to a separate environment
- Live reload development server
- File watching (rebuild on changes)

With vast support of open source community all these things are very easy to do in Gulp/Grunt. Apart from it Gulp/Grunt became the first class citizen in asp net core.

So i think these are the enough reasons to move to Gulp/Grunt based environment.